# How to implement a TYPO3 9.5 RSS Feed for Pages

Tags: typo3, rss, typo3-9.x, rss2

i researched a bit but was not able to find a fitting solution. the problem is quite simple we just need to output a rss feed for our custom blog pages. we have a blog page and the child pages are the actual blog records so to speak - other periphere systems require that structure. now my question is what would be the approach within TYPO3 to actually generate RSS feeds for every of those child pages?

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plugin.tx_seo {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            20 = EXT:ds_site/Resources/Private/Templates/Sitemaps/
        }
    }
    config {
        xmlSitemap {
            sitemaps {
                rssFeedAllBlogPosts {
                    provider = TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\RecordsXmlSitemapDataProvider
                    config {
                        table = pages
                        sortField = tstamp
                        lastModifiedField = tstamp
                        additionalWhere = AND (no_index = 0 OR no_follow = 0)
                        pid = 2
                        recursive = 3
                        template = RssFeed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>Daniel Siepmann - Coding is Art</title>
        <description>List of blog posts at daniel-siepmann.de</description>
        <link>{f:uri.page(pageUid: 1, absolute: 1)}</link>
        <atom:link href="{f:uri.page(pageUid: 1. pageType: 1533906435, additionalParams: {sitemap: 'rssFeedAllBlogPosts'}, absolute: 1)}" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <lastBuildDate>{f:format.date(date: 'now', format: 'D, d M Y H:i:s O')}</lastBuildDate>
        <ttl>1800</ttl>

        <f:for each="{items}" as="item">
            <f:if condition="{item.data.doktype} < 200">
                {f:render(section: 'Item', arguments: {
                    item: item.data
                })}
            </f:if>
        </f:for>
    </channel>
</rss>

<f:section name="Item">
    <item>
        <title>{item.title}</title>
        <description>{item.abstract}</description>
        <link>{f:uri.page(pageUid: item.uid, absolute: 1)}</link>
        <pubDate>{f:format.date(date: item.lastUpdated, format: 'D, d M Y H:i:s O')}</pubDate>
        <guid isPermaLink="true">{f:uri.page(pageUid: item.uid, absolute: 1)}</guid>
    </item>
</f:section>
```

You can use this one as a reference implementation. That's what I use for my website. Of course you need to adjust it accordingly, e.g. `pid` might be different, as well as extension key `ds_site`, etc.

Also note, this one uses EXT:seo, a system extension of TYPO3, providing sitemap features.

You can link to the feed: `<a href="{f:uri.page(pageUid: 1, pageType: 1533906435, additionalParams: {sitemap: 'rssFeedAllBlogPosts'})}">RSS Feed</a>`.

Also you might wanna adjust url routing:

```
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    default: .html
    map:
      .xml: 1533906435
      .html: 0
  Feed:
    type: Simple
    limitToPages:
      - 1
    routePath: '/feed/{sitemap_id}'
    requirements:
      sitemap_id: '[a-zA-Z].*'
    _arguments:
      sitemap: sitemap_id
```

Comment: Note that TYPO3 does not provide a proper way to sort the entries. As RSS != Sitemap, this might not be added in future.